# How can I define dynamic class member?

Tags: c#, html, class, nodes

I have a list which is like:

```
       <option value="245">Adam Adam</option>
       <option value="427">Adnan KAYA</option>
       <option value="347">Ahmet Ağaoğlu</option>
       <option value="150">Ahmet ALTAN</option>
       <option value="337">Ahmet Arsan</option>
```

and I get this values with:

```
         var noa = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(""); 
          for (int y = 1; y < noa.ChildNodes.Count; y++)
           {
            var s = noa.ChildNodes[y].Attributes["value"].Value;
            var ss = noa.ChildNodes[y+1].InnerText;
            }
```

I have a class

```
    public class aut
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

is it possible to write this inside of for loop?

```
     aut ss=new aut();
     ss.id=s;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It sounds like you want a `List<aut>()` where `aut` has 1 member named `id`, which is mapped to `value` in the xml. Is that correct? Also the xml in the post is missing a root element.

Comment: @MikeHixson I want this like: adamadam.id=245,adnankaya.id=427, ahmetağoğlu.id=347...    I tried what you said. defined List<aut> auts = new List<aut>(); outside of for loop. and wrote auts[y].id = Convert.ToInt32(s); inside of it. (y=0,1,2...) it gives the " Index was out of range." error

Comment: You probably dont really want the names of your data as the class name like you have indicated. Maybe you want a dictionary like this `data["adamadam"].id = 245` or you want a list like `list.Add(new { id = 245, name = "adamadam" })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
    var autList = new List<aut>();
    var noa = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("");
    for (int y = 1; y < noa.ChildNodes.Count; y++)
    {
        autList.Add(new aut() { id = Convert.ToInt32(noa.ChildNodes[y].Attributes["value"].Value)});
    }
```